# Perception of rainbows

Tags: visible-light, reflection

Does the shape of a rainbow have anything to do with the concave shaped back of a raindrop, from which the light is reflected?

Answer (score 0):

In some sense: yes. All is described by reflection and refaction in the raindrop. It is rather complex theory. Some description you have in Scientific American article: http://www.phys.uwosh.edu/rioux/genphysII/pdf/rainbows.pdf